Can't you use `,` operator to define a variable in a while loop's expression in C?
Why can't we define a variable in while loop's condition expression in the same way as we can define in a for loop?
For example:
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    while((int c = getchar()) != EOF) 
         printf("%c", c);
    
    return 0;
}

Chat GPT 4.0 and Perplexity.ai had suggested me the above piece of code. But apparently that's not allowed; I found  out that through trail and error. I also tried using , operator too.
Example:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while((int c = getchar(), c != EOF) 
         printf("%c", c);
    
    return 0;
}

As the value of the conditional test is only going to be the right most expression (c != EOF) because , operator was used. But even then the compiler didn't compile it. So, how can we define a variable in the while loop's conditional expression?

Because the language syntax allows one, but not the other.

"in the same way as we can define in a for loop?": What you wrote in the examples doesn't work with for either. In a for loop the init clause (which can be a declaration for a variable) is separated by ; from the condition, not ,. Having a declaration inside an expression as in (int c = getchar()) != EOF is just not at all possible in the language syntax. ChatGPT is suggesting non-sense to you.

OT: Why do you need/want to use while() instead of the obvious for() that is both idiomatic and syntactically correct?

"Chat GPT 4.0 and Perplexity.ai had suggested..." They are no replacement for learning material. They don't really know how to program. Learning a programming language by trial and error is very likely to cause a lot of frustration.

The syntax of the while statement does not allow variables to be declared in the controlling expression (it's an expression, not a declaration). You could use a for loop instead, although there will be some code repetition:
   /* ^^ preceding code ^^ */
   for (int c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar())
       /* loop statement */;

If the repetition of the call to getchar() is unacceptable and the variable c must be isolated, there are various options. As pointed out by user tstanisl in the comments below, the assignment could be combined with the test in the controlling expression of the for loop:
   /* ^^ preceding code ^^ */
   for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF; )
       /* loop statement */;

The controlling expression of the loop could also be a comma expression to separate the assignment from the test:
   /* ^^ preceding code ^^ */
   for (int c; c = getchar(), c != EOF; )
       /* loop statement */;

Another option mentioned in the answer by user Allan Wind is to place the while loop inside an enclosing block that defines the variable c:
   /* ^^ preceding code ^^ */
   {
       /* local declarations for the loop */
       int c;
       while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
           /* loop statement */;
   }

The above use of an enclosing block is useful if several declarations are required to define the variables local to the loop and its condition test, whether that be a while loop, a do while loop, or a for loop.
Another option mentioned in the answer by user Allan Wind is to use an infinite loop with a conditional break statement to terminate the loop. The local variables can be defined in the compound statement that forms the body of the infinite loop:
   /* ^^ preceding code ^^ */
   for (;;)
   {
       int c = getchar();
       if (c == EOF)
       {
           break;
       }
       /* remainder of loop */
   }


Why not combine both methods to for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ) ?

@tstanisl Thanks, I have extended my answer to incorporate your suggestion with some other changes.

No. Its not allowed by language syntax but GCC compiler (and clang as well) allow it as an extension, known as statement expression.
GCC's statement expression allow you to use local variables within an expression. Take your sample code as example, we can declare local variable c in while loop expression if using GCC compiler, but it will not be accessible in loop body as it is only available within expression.
Using GCC's statement expression extension, your sample code can be written as:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while(({int c = getchar(); c == EOF ? 0 : putchar(c);})) 
         ;
    return 0;
}


@AllanWind This is OP's question how can we define a variable in the while loop's conditional expression? - which is something not allowed in C language. In my post I have provided details about a gcc compiler extension which can be used to do what OP want to and it comes with some limitations. For the last one - better in terms of what?

Easier to reason about truth that false expression.   My questions was really only to help you possible improve your answer.

@AllanWind Included your suggestion. Thanks.
